# If I run npm build on a react app with unnecessary dependencies, will it still bundle those dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dependency-management

Let's say that I have a react app that I've created with create-react-app.

I've installed useless-dependency, but I haven't called it anywhere in my app. I didn't install it as a dev dependency, just as a regular dependency.

Then I run npm build on my app. Will useless-dependency be bundled in with my app, or will the final build be clever enough to ignore it?

Comment: This mechanizm - of removing dead code called [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/). create-react-app has it out of the box.

Comment: Not unless you use them in your code.